# componentWillReceiveProps not receiving props after clicking a Link component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, url-routing

We are creating our first React app to create an e-commerce site using the Shopify Buy SDK.

Right now the correct data is being rendered by the ProductDetail component if a user goes directly to a path like the following: `/product/SOMEPRODUCT_ID`

However, when the user clicks on a ProductCard component, the data for the clicked-on product does not render in a ProductDetail component.

To determine the correct data associated with the ProductDetail component, we created the `getCurrentProduct` method which is called during the `componentWillReceiveProps` lifecycle hook. Both the ProductCard and ProductDetail components have access to `this.props.products` which is an array of all of the products.

Is there any lifecycle hook that will allow us to get the products from `this.props` when the user clicks on a link from the ProductCard component?

Below is the ProductDetail component.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class ProductDetail extends Component {
  constructor() {

    super();

    this.state = {
      product: {}
    };

    this.getCurrentProduct = this.getCurrentProduct.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {

    this.getCurrentProduct(nextProps.products);
  }

  getCurrentProduct(products) {

    const slug = this.context.match.parent.params.id;

    const product = products.filter(product => {
      return product.handle === slug;
    })[0];

    this.setState({ product });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <main className="view view--home">
        {this.state.product.title}
      </main>
    );
  }
}

ProductDetail.contextTypes = {
  match: React.PropTypes.object
}

export default ProductDetail;
```

Below is the ProductCard component.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';

class ProductCard extends Component {
  render() {
    const { details } = this.props;
    return (
      <figure className="product-card">
        <Link to={`/product/${this.props.id}`}>
          <img src={details.images[0].src} alt={details.title} className="product-card__thumbnail" />
        </Link>
        <Link to={`/product/${this.props.id}`}>
          <figcaption className="product-card__body">
            <h3 className="product-card__title">{details.title}</h3>
            <span className="product-card__price">{details.rendered_price}</span>
          </figcaption>
        </Link>
      </figure>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lifecycle method `componentWillReceiveProps` is invoked before a mounted component receives new props. So, this method will not be called when component is mounted. Here you need to call `getCurrentProduct()` in `componentWillMount()` lifecycle method.

Comment: Thank you very much! That's makes a ton of sense.